# Can a Tier 2 UK Work visa holder, who also holds India Passport, visit Republic of Ireland? Without issuing a separate Irish Visa?

Tags: visas, uk, common-travel-area

I will be traveling to UK on work visa (Tier 2 - Intra company transfer). Of course, i will also be holding my India passport. 
Will I be allowed to travel to Dublin, Republic of Ireland based on Tier 2 Work visa?
I meant without the extra effort for applying for separate Irish visa?

Comment: As I know there is no immgration control between the boundaries of 2 country

Comment: You need a visa, but you willn't need to pay the visa fees.

Comment: For T2's in the Common Travel Area, you can also use http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions for other/similar questions

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate, abense of border enforcement doesn't nesacerally mean that the same visas are acceptable on both sides.